# HP Pavilion P6210Y [Pegatron M2N78-LA Motherboard] will NOT detect replacement Western Digital 640GB SATA Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata, hardware-failure, hardware-detection

I'm working on an HP Pavilion P6210Y (Pegatron M2N78-LA motherboard) that's hard drive has crashed. The issue that I'm running in to is that for some reason the computer absolutely REFUSES to detect the replacement drive I'm attempting to install, despite the fact that I KNOW the hard drive is good as I just pulled it out a a striping RAID setup in which it worked flawlessly.

The HP's original HD was a Western Digital Caviar WD6400AAKS. The drive I'm attempting to replace it with is a one year older Western Digital WD6400AAKS. If I just hit the power switch on the machine it'll load to the BIOS POST splash page and just hang. If I hit F10 to get into the BIOS setup quickly then it'll load the BIOS, but only the DVD drive is detected. There is no hint that the hard drive is plugged in at all.

I've tried different SATA ports, resetting the BIOS to its defaults, using the same SATA cable that the replacement drive was using in the RAID setup in the other machine, etc. Nothing I've done will make this blasted computer detect that the drive exists. I've checked the P6210Y's product support page on HP's website and see no BIOS updates that I could try.

Suggestions?

Comment: It worked in the RAID it used to be in.  Test it again now on another system.  If the mobo in that HP caused the original drive to crash, it could have damaged the replacement

Comment: Gets detected fine when connected to my test rig, was able to create partitions, format them, etc.

Comment: Then you may have discovered the reason/issue for the original drive crash.  The motherboard.  You can try another different drive, but at this point you should expect the same results.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read about this specific HP system, it's a defective motherboard issue. The motherboard causes the hard drive to fail. If you put in a new hard drive, it may be destroyed as well. You have to replace the motherboard, and start with a fresh hard drive.

Comment: Agree with this. Have reached the same conclusion and replaced a motherboard in a similar system. If you carefully examine the board you may be able to spot a burned-out component, although it's not always visible to the human eye.